# c# "?" in method declaration

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# at the moment, and I have never seen this before.

```
static int? Foo()
{
    return Bar
}
```

What does the "?" do?

I did try looking it up on Google and SE but I don't really know what key terms I should be searching for.

Comment: It is a nullable type. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx
Assign a value to a nullable type just as you would for an ordinary value type, for example int? x = 10; or double? d = 4.108. A nullable type can also be assigned the value null: int? x = null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `int?` is a nullable int. Using this as the return type of your method means that this method returns either an int or null. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

> Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable struct. A
>   nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its
>   underlying value type, plus an additional null value. For example, a
>   Nullable, pronounced "Nullable of Int32," can be assigned any
>   value from -2147483648 to 2147483647, or it can be assigned the null
>   value.

Comment: @danielr pls check this link, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx. It answers your question. If the answer is not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

`int?` = the value can be integer or null

Answer (score 0):

`int?` is a type and is equivalent to `Nullable<int>`.
This type can store an Integer or Null.

Answer (score 0):

`int?` is the shorthand for `Nullable<int>` More info here: [**Nullable ᐸTᐳ Structure**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

It allows you to have `"null"` values in your int. More info here: [**Using Nullable Types**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

This is a syntactic shortcut to define a nullable type, which is usually defined using the type `Nullable<T>`